# How to disable navigation on WinForm with arrows in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I need to disable changing focus with arrows on form. Is there an easy way how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            control.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(control_PreviewKeyDown);
        }
    }

    void control_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            e.IsInputKey = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!
Just short note for other people: foreach (Control control in this.Controls) does not contain all controls - you may have containers (e.g., system.windows.forms.panel) on form.

Comment: Wouldn't have thought of that, but that seems to completely work. (My goal was to conditionally disable Enter, but same idea.) Thanks!

Comment: Ah thank you! The key was PreviewKeyDown event instead of KeyDown event. I was trying to solve the issue under KeyDown event but once I set space key as input key it solved. Now my buttons don't get clicked with space :)

Answer (score 5):

I've ended up with the code below which set the feature to EVERY control on form:

(The code is based on the one from andynormancx)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetFeatureToAllControls(this.Controls);    
}

private void SetFeatureToAllControls(Control.ControlCollection cc)
{
    if (cc != null)
    {
        foreach (Control control in cc)
        {
            control.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(control_PreviewKeyDown);
            SetFeatureToAllControls(control.Controls);
        }
    }
}

void control_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `KeyPreview` to true on the form. Handle the `KeyDown/KeyUp/KeyPress` event and set the `e.Handled` in the eventhandler to true for the keys you want to be ignored.

Comment: That approach doesn't seems to work, there is no e.Handled on the PreviewKeyDownEventArgs

Comment: e.Handled exists but in method: private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e), KeyDown etc. I have problems with this approach too. I'll try it on clean project.

Comment: Yes it exists in the KeyDown event, but setting it doesn't help, the navigation has already happened by that point.

Comment: I wasn't sure when the navigation was made. The advice below works great.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this aproach, where the form handles the preview event once. It generates less code than the other options.

Just add this method to the `PreviewKeyDown` event of your form, and set the `KeyPreview` property to `true`.

```
private void form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Right:
            e.IsInputKey = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi carlos. I wanted to use your shorter version, but when I tested it, it did not do what it should unfortunately.. (and I did remember to set `Form.KeyPreview=true` of course). Only when I added the foreach() in Form_Load, then the behavior changed.. Have you tested it?

Comment: this does not work if the form contains more than one level of container hierarchies.