# How to prevent focus switching with keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf

When you have several controls, normally you can switch the focus simply by arrow keys. But in my current case this is undesired.

How to disable such focus switching? I already have set `TabIndex` to `-1`.

Comment: So when _should_ your controls lose focus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable navigation on WinForm with arrows in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318236/how-to-disable-navigation-on-winform-with-arrows-in-c)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott, when user clicks on other one with mouse. Why do you ask?

Comment: In that case i486's answer should do what your looking for.

Comment: Have you tried these properties ?  <Button
                Focusable="False"
                FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None" 
                KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="None" 
                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None">

Answer (score 0):

Handle KeyDown event for the form and set e.Handled = true when the key is Tab. Set KeyPreview = true for the form.

Comment: Thank you, but WPF window does not have `KeyPreview` property, and I am not talking about Tab (this is easy), but arrow keys.

Comment: In WPF there is similar event - add attribute `PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"`. I tried this and it disabled left arrow: `private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("preview {0}", e.Key);
            if (e.Key == Key.Left)
                e.Handled = true;
        }`