# C# WinForms: bring back focus to form after button click

Tags: c#, winforms

my simple WinForms app consists of one Form which has 2 important methods:

```
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
    {
        qKeyPressed = true;
    }
    keyTimer.Start();
}

private void MainWindow_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
    {
        qKeyPressed = false;
    }
    keyTimer.Stop();
}
```

In form's constructor I use `button1.TabStop = false;` to set button1 focus to `false`, so my form can handle methods `KeyUp` and `KeyDown`. I want my form to be focused even after `button1` click event. I tried:

```
button1.TabStop = false;
this.Focus();
```

in `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` but this doesn't seem to work and button after click looks like focused and methods `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` are disabled. How can my problem be solved? Thanks in advance

Comment: Implement IMessageFilter instead so you can see the key messages regardless of which control has the focus.

Comment: If you are seeking for a button which can only be clicked, but never get focused, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823525/how-to-stop-pressing-button-using-keyboard-keys-like-spacebar-or-enter-c-shar/32825190#32825190

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this in the button click function:

```
this.ActiveControl = null;
```

When you click the button, you set it as the active control. Removing this property will let you put focus on your form.

Comment: Thanks, It works great, I don'know why somebody gave your answer a minus

Comment: Yeah, me neither. Glad to help!