# Move PictureBox using Arrow Keys - Handle keyboard events in PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox, keypress

I have a `PictureBox` where I use the code below to move my object. I need to add a few buttons in the form, however when I start the program the arrow keys navigate through the buttons instead of my input keypresses. I've tried many 
ways like `PictureBox.Focus()` and `PictureBox.Select()` on `Form.Load()`, and disabling the arrow key navigation completely on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318308), but my object will not move anymore.

```
private void UpdateScreen(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Right) && Settings.direction != Direction.Left) {
        Settings.direction = Direction.Right;
    }
    else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Left) && Settings.direction != Direction.Right) {
        Settings.direction = Direction.Left;
    }  
    else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Up) && Settings.direction != Direction.Down) {
        Settings.direction = Direction.Up;
    }
    else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Down) && Settings.direction != Direction.Up) {
        Settings.direction = Direction.Down;
    }
}
```

How do I just disable the arrow key navigation for all my buttons without affecting my code in `UpdateScreen()`?

Comment: `PictureBox` control is not `Selectable`. To solve the problem, you should make the `PictureBox` selectable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PictureBox` control is not `Selectable` and therefore it can not handle Keyboard events. To solve the problem, you should first make the control selectable:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class SelectablePictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public SelectablePictureBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);
        TabStop = true;
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnter(e);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLeave(e);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        if (this.Focused)
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pe.Graphics, ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Then you can handle `PreviewKeyDown` event of it:

```
private void selectablePictureBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender,
    PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
        myPictureBox1.Left -= 10;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
        myPictureBox1.Left += 10;
    }
}
```