# C# Windows Forms PictureBox moving with Keys (w,a,s,d) doesnt work because wrong selection? (Coding NewBie)

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I'm planning on doing a Jump and Run, so I need a moving pictureBox if I press W / A / S / D or something like that. I'm currently using the source code down there.

The Problem I have right now is, that I've got a lot of Buttons, other Picture Frames, text boxes etc in my current Form1 and if I press the button W now, my picture box won't get higher in coordinates because I think one of the other buttons etc is selected, does anybody know how to fix that?
I tried the Source code in a new file without any other Buttons textboxes etc and it worked without any problems.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            pictureBox2.Top -= 100;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake in the title

Comment: You can edit your post again if you want to fix anything.

Comment: Did put a breakpoint and debug ?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya yes

Comment: i also tried "pictureBox2.BringToFront();" but no change

Comment: `PictureBox` is not selectable control. You need to handle form key events or make the picture box selectable. Take a look at: [Move PicutreBox using Arrow Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48367078/3110834)

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `KeyPreview` property of the `form` to `true`, so you will get the key strokes *before* they reach the controls.

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-at-the-form-level)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `KeyPreview` of the Form to True in order to get the `Form1_KeyDown` to run when others objects in the Form are selected