# calling DataGridView.EndEdit() from picturebox click event doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using a DataGridView with no binding a datasource. How can I end the datagridview editing mode by clicking on a picturebox. I've tested EndEdit() in picturebox click event, but seems it doesn't work.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgv.EndEdit();
    }
```

Comment: I am not following what you are asking. You state that.. _”Calling DataGridView.EndEdit() from a button click event works well and ends the current cell editing mode.”_ … ? … technically this is NOT true. The `Button` didn’t end the edit, the grid ended the edit as soon as it lost focus… when the `Button` was clicked.

Comment: As soon as the user presses the button AND just before the grid loses focus… the grid will call its `EndEdit` method if a cell was being edited when the user clicked the button. The same would apply to the picture box. I am just wondering “why” you need to end the grids edit from the button or picture box, when the grid has already done this for you automatically.

Comment: @JohnG Yes you're right. I didn't realized. But the same does not happen to the picturebox when I click on it and the datagrideview does not lost its focus. Actually I don't have a button in my form. All I have are picturebox. So how can I end the edit mode by clicking on a picturebox while the datagridview doesn't lost its focus?

Comment: Try this… when you use a `MessageBox` to help debug a UI app, then this can get messed up in a timing sense that the UI may ignore things if you take too long to close the message box. To help, I suggest you replace the `MessageBox` lines of code with `Debug` statements… `Debug.WriteLine("CellEndEdit...");` Then this “timing” problem doesn’t happen. If you do this and put a debug statement in each of the events… you will see that the GRIDS end edit is ALWAYS called BEFORE the picture box click is executed. You will need a `using` statement for the debug statements `using System.Diagnostics;`

Comment: @JohnG Thank you JohnG, but clicking on a picturebox does NOT get the focus from a grid view editing cell and CellEndEdit event doesn't fired in my winform.

Comment: `dgv.CurrentCell = null` may do the trick.

Comment: Well after a little more testing I can see what you are describing. A `Button` click will fire the grids end edit whereas a picture box click does not. However, in my test the line of code… `dgv.EndEdit();` … appears to work as expected. This took the cell out of edit mode and the whole cell was simply highlighted as the selected cell. Sorry but your current solution worked in my small tests.

Comment: EndEdit works as expected, it ends edit. If you want to know why clicking on PictureBox, doesn't movie the focus from DataGridView to PictureBox, that's because PictureBox has a style to make it non-selectable; while you can [make PictureBox selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370681/3110834), but I'm not sure why you want to do this?

Comment: The `CellEndEdit` is raised when a cell in the grid is `dirty` (the value has been changed). Calling the `.EndEdit()` method with no dirty cells does not fire the event. As for why the grid does not lose the focus when you click a `PictureBox`, because the [PictureBox is not a selectable control](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,127).

Comment: Did you try to set focus to the pbox : `pictureBox1.Focus()` - You need to do it in code, as pbox will not grab it by itself. (It is not really meant as an interactice control)

Comment: @dr.null `CellEndEdit` doesn't raised even when I change the cell value.

Comment: @TaW I consider your comment as the answer (workaround to the problem). Calling `pictureBox1.Focus()' in click event removes the focus from the datagridview. Thanks

Comment: From your question: **The point is that datagridview won't lose its focus when I click on the picturebox.** and from your comment: **Calling pictureBox1.Focus() in click event removes the focus from the datagridview.**. Sorry, you contradict yourself.

Comment: @dr.null Clicking on a picturebox does not end editing mode, while calling `picturebox.Focus()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `EndEdit()` won't end the editing mode if `DataGridView.EditMode` is set to `EditOnEnter`.